# the data type "char" in java

Tags: java

why doesnt any of these work:

```
 char word = "sds";
 char word = 'sds';
 myDog.bark("voff");
 myDog.bark('voff');
```

in the object to myDog i have typed:

```
 void bark(char word) {
      System.out.println(word);
 }
```

Comment: If you want a better explanation, you could post the error message you are receiving and you could learn how to interpret it.  (Currently, I don't have a java dev environment handy.)

Comment: This guy has 158 questions, about half of which look like they'd be covered in chapters 1-4 of any beginning java book.

Comment: Which would possibly make SO a good reference for those searching for quick answers on google.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because a char is just a single character. You want to use the String type instead.

```
void bark(String word) {
   System.out.println(word);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to use "String" not "char". char is only for 1 character, "String" is for multiple characters.

With "String" type you use double-quotes, with "char" you use single quotes:

```
char c = 'a';
String s = "hello";
```

Answer (score 3):

The char data type can only contain one character.  For multiple characters, you should use the String data type.

Answer (score 2):

char is one character, String is a sequence of chars. You are looking for a String